# Match low and highest prices in a block of HTML using jQuery each and javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to loop through a block of elements to determine the lowest occurring price. I have the loop working but trying to regex the price is proving difficult.

Where am I going wrong with the regex?

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#>Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£20.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#>Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£20.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#>Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price"><span class="rrp"£40.00</span>£20.00</em></p>
</div>
```

The overall aim is to get the highest and lowest occurring prices within all of the html?
**Javascript / jQuery**

```
var highPrice;
var lowPrice;

$(".block").each(function(){

    var currentPriceHtml = $(this).html();
    var m;

    do{

        //match the following prices
        //<span class="rrp">£40.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£30.00 
        //£15.00 
        //£20.00 
        //£10.00 

        m = currentPriceHtml.exec(/^-?\$?[0-9]*\.?([0-9]{2})?%?$/);

        if(m){
            console.log(m[1], m[2]);

            if(!highPrice || m[1] > highPrice)
                highPrice = m1[1]; //set highest occurring price

            if(!lowPrice || m[1] < lowPrice)
                lowPrice = m[1]; //set lowest occurring price

        }
    }
    while(currentPriceHtml);

    console.log("High Price: " + highPrice);
    console.log("Low Price: " + lowPrice);
});
```

Comment: try instead: `m = window.parseInt(currentPriceHtml.replace(/\D*/g, ""), 10);`

Comment: What is this `<em class="price"><span class="rrp"£40.00</span>£20.00</em>`?

Comment: @zvona that ran over 200,00 matches? 
That is a sale price with the rrp in a span

Comment: True. Dots and commas gets stripped, needs enhancement.

Comment: So what from the two `<span class="rrp">£40.00</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£30.00 ` you need?

Comment: The lowest, so the one not in the span.

Comment: If you take a look at my answer, the min and max are as expected (the rrp is ignored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code a little. What about something like this:

```js
var prices = $('.block .price').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/(\d+\.\d{2})/)[1];
}).get();

var min = Math.min.apply(null, prices);
alert(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£20.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£19.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price"><span class="rrp">£40.00</span> £20.00</em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, also `var max= Math.max.apply(null, prices);` gets the highest as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly alternative version which takes into account the block with the rrp price, this takes everything after the last instance of '£':

```
    var prices = [];
    $('.price').each(function () {
        var price = $(this).text().match(/[^£]*$/);
        prices.push(price);
    })

    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, prices);
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);
    alert(min + ' ' + max);
```

I updated the html to make it a little clearer which values were selected:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£20.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price">£35.00</em></p>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
    <p><em class="price"><span class="rrp">£40.00</span>£10.00</em></p>
</div>
```

This results in a minimum of 10 and a maximum of 35.